# Can Firebase/FCM deliver scheduled notifications with no internet and app not running?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have read the FCM can deliver notifications to Android-phones for an app, even if that app isn't running, either after a reboot or force close, since it uses Google Play services. Can anyone confirm this, and if so, what's the minimum OS-version of Android for this to work?

Also, does the same go for iOS? Can FCM deliver notifications without the app running at all?

Basically what I want to do is have FCM deliver notifications scheduled for display some time in the future to Android and iOS, so store and display these even if the phone is off the grid and the app is not running. If possible, is there a max number of scheduled notifications Android and iOS can store?

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

Firebase Cloud Messaging can indeed deliver messages to the device even when your app is not running. There's no specific minimum version for this functionality, as it's been in Android since its first release, but check the Firebase documentation for the minimum version of the SDK you use.

---

It is also possible to deliver a message now for display at a later time. For that you'll want to send a [`data` message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) and then in your [code that receives the message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#override-onmessagereceived) schedule a job to later display a local notification.

---

All of this is covered both in the Firebase documentation, but also in many tutorials out there. I recommend searching for some of those, giving them a try, and reporting back with a more concrete question if you can't get it to work.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your reply :-) 

Yes, I know that it's possible to schedule the message for later if the app is running and can intercept the message, but what if the app is not running - then my code that would normally process the incoming data, won't catch it? 

Do you know if there's any difference between Android and iOS and how they can interact with incoming FCM, either in background or without the app running at all?

Comment: Messages are received in `FirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived`, which runs as a background service - so even when the user is not useing the app.